# Customize "view" action in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am new to ruby on rails and working on a project with ruby on rails 4th version. right now i was changing the view of the order in active admin but i am getting errors.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
    permit_params :id, :order_completed, :approved

    # changing the visual of view action, so admin user can able to see complete order details
    show do |order|
        attributes_table do
            row :id # Order ID
            row 'Name' params[:user].first_name # its not working, not showing the user first_name assiated with order id 
            # It should be user name. although user first_name is in users table and User model is availble.
            row 'Adress' params[:user].address # its not working, not showing the user address assiated with order id
            # It should be user address. although user first_name is in users table and User model is availble.
        end
    end

    controller do
        def show 
            order_id = Order.find(params[:id]).user_id
            params[:user] = User.find(order_id)
            show!
        end
    end
end
```

My goal is to show order associated user's details like address, name etc.

**Order table consists of**

```
 - id
 - user_id
 - order_completed (boolean)
 - approved
 - order_status (string) [in process, done]
```

**User table consists of**

```
 - id
 - first_name
 - last_name
 - address
 - membership_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assuming that you have established the relationship between the class 'Order' and the class 'User' in their respective models. (belongs_to and has_many methods. If you need more help on this let me know.) 
Then **you have to declare that relationship also in Activeadmin** when you register the classes, so try this:

```
    app/admin/order.rb:
    ActiveAdmin.register Order do
        permit_params :id, :order_completed, :approved
        belongs_to :user # Declaring that order belongs to user here

        # changing the visual of view action, so admin user can able to see complete order details
        show do |order|
            attributes_table do
                row :id # Order ID
                row 'Name' do
                    @order.user.first_name
                end
                row 'Address' do 
                    @order.user.address
                end
            end
        end

        controller do
            def show 
                @order = Order.find(params[:id])
                show!
            end
        end
    end`
```